# HTML 5 audio looping issue

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have a web based game which uses HTML5 audio feature. I use it to loop the background music once the game (level starts). Everything runs fine, the problem i'm facing is that after 4-5 loops, the background music gets distorted resulting in rough music output. How to solve this issue or is this the limitation in browsers?

Since browsers are not supporting HTML5 audio looping functionality, i have used javascript to do this. Here is my code snippet:

```
bgmusic = new Audio('music.mp3'); 
   bgmusic.addEventListener('ended', function() {
   this.currentTime = 0;
   this.play();
 }, false);
bgmusic.play();
```

Comment: could you provide a snippet to the code?

Comment: What about `bgmusic.loop = true` ?

Comment: They *do* support looping, but this sounds like a bug. Is this FF?

Comment: looping is supported only in firefox, it doesn't work in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

To loop the track you could do instead:

```
var bgmusic = new Audio();
bgmusic.loop = true;        // enable looping
bgmusic.autoplay = true;    // autoplay when data is ready
bgmusic.src = 'music.mp3';  // start loading data
```

However, if you get distorted sound, it indicates a browser bug. I would suggest reporting it to the vendor.